# Mobile app development issues with qmlviewer not being found?

Tags: application-development, qt-creator, qml

I am trying to follow the Mobile app development tutorial [found here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/mobile/currency-converter-phone-app/). When I try to run the currency converter in QT Creator I get this error:

`Starting external tool '/usr/bin/qmlviewer' ''`
`qmlviewer: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmlviewer': No such file or directory`

I'm not sure how to fix this?  I can run the program from the command line and it runs fine but it doesn't work in Qt Creator.  Has any one else had these issues?  Any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: you have to use qmlscene, if you have QtQuick 2.0 like in the tutorial. How do you try to run the app in Qt Creator?

Comment: I didn't set the shortcut ctrl+shift+p properly.  Everything works now!  Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @Sarah What do you mean with Ctrl+Shift+P? It is just a shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install QML toolkit. run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk notepad-qml
```

Comment: the QML from this website has nothing to do with the QML from the question

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ubuntu Software Centre and find 'Qt4 QML viewer'. Install it. should work now.

Answer (score 0):

To view `QtQuick 2.0` you have to use `qmlscene`

Comment: Well, yes, but the problem is that `qtcreator` presupposes `qmlviewer`. That is the problem.